# Selecting same MSSQL table with different condition to get the difference

Tags: sql-server, join, conditional-statements

I have a table FinTrans As

```
Seq|Ledger|Debit_Credit|Amount
1  |130000|Debit       |105
2  |120000|Debit       |1456
3  |130000|Credit      |500
4  |130000|Debit       |9680
5  |130000|Credit      |1432
6  |120000|Debit       |1628
```

I want to find (sum of Debit Amount) - (sum of Credit Amount) for each ledger.

```
For eg.in above case for Ledger 130000 
the sum of Debit Amount = 105+9680 = 9785
the sum of Credit Amount = 500 +1432=1537
Difference = 8248
```

How can I write a SQL query on the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a `CASE` expression inside an aggregate function. This is called conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT Ledger, SUM(Amount * CASE WHEN Debit_Credit = 'Credit' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) As Difference
FROM FinTrans
 -- WHERE Ledger = 130000 -- optional
GROUP BY d.Ledger
```

It works here because of the commutative property, which says you don't have to add up all the credits and debits separately to subtract one from the other; you can do all the additions and subtractions in any order and still end up with the same result.

If you really want to, you can do it this way:

```
SELECT Ledger, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Debit_Credit = 'Debit' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END)
  - SUM(CASE WHEN Debit_Credit = 'Credit' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) As Difference
FROM FinTrans
 -- WHERE Ledger = 130000 -- optional
GROUP BY d.Ledger
```

It more resembles the problem description. But it's more complicated and slower, and again, it's not needed.